# Error while trying to upload code to NodeMcu that will let me control a LED Matrix

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I have a code that I downloaded from a webpage that is supposed to let me control a MAX7219 LED Matrix from a Web Interface using an ESP8266 (I'm using a NodeMcu v3.0 with an ESP8266-12E), but every time I try to compile the code, the following error comes out:

> MAX7219_ESP8266:45: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' to 'MD_MAX72XX::moduleType_t' [-fpermissive]
>
> MD_MAX72XX mx = MD_MAX72XX(CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);
>
> ^
>
> In file included from
>   E:\Searches\Desktop\MAX7219_ESP8266\MAX7219_ESP8266.ino:14:0:
>
> E:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MD_MAX72XX\src/MD_MAX72xx.h:362:3:
>   error:   initializing argument 1 of
>   'MD_MAX72XX::MD_MAX72XX(MD_MAX72XX::moduleType_t, uint8_t, uint8_t)'
>   [-fpermissive]
>
> MD_MAX72XX(moduleType_t mod, uint8_t csPin, uint8_t numDevices=1);
>
> ^
>
> exit status 1 invalid conversion from 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' to
>   'MD_MAX72XX::moduleType_t' [-fpermissive]

What could I do in order to fix it? I tried using a different library and even modifying the library, but the same error came out.

The code is the following:

```
// IP address for the ESP8266 is displayed on the scrolling display
// after startup initialisation and connected to the WiFi network.
//
// Connections for ESP8266 hardware SPI are:
// Vcc       3v3     LED matrices seem to work at 3.3V
// GND       GND     GND
// DIN        D7     HSPID or HMOSI
// CS or LD   D8     HSPICS or HCS
// CLK        D5     CLK or HCLK
//

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <MD_MAX72xx.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define PRINT_CALLBACK  0
#define DEBUG 0
#define LED_HEARTBEAT 0

#if DEBUG
#define PRINT(s, v) { Serial.print(F(s)); Serial.print(v); }
#define PRINTS(s)   { Serial.print(F(s)); }
#else
#define PRINT(s, v)
#define PRINTS(s)
#endif


#if LED_HEARTBEAT
#define HB_LED  D2
#define HB_LED_TIME 500 // in milliseconds
#endif

// Define the number of devices we have in the chain and the hardware interface
// NOTE: These pin numbers will probably not work with your hardware and may
// need to be adapted
#define MAX_DEVICES 4

#define CLK_PIN     D5 // or SCK
#define DATA_PIN    D7 // or MOSI
#define CS_PIN      D8 // or SS

// SPI hardware interface
MD_MAX72XX mx = MD_MAX72XX(CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);
// Arbitrary pins
//MD_MAX72XX mx = MD_MAX72XX(DATA_PIN, CLK_PIN, CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);

// WiFi login parameters - network name and password
const char* ssid = "your SSID";                   // edit your wifi SSID here
const char* password = "your Password";            // edit your wifi password here

// WiFi Server object and parameters
WiFiServer server(80);

// Global message buffers shared by Wifi and Scrolling functions
const uint8_t MESG_SIZE = 255;
const uint8_t CHAR_SPACING = 1;
const uint8_t SCROLL_DELAY = 75;

char curMessage[MESG_SIZE];
char newMessage[MESG_SIZE];
bool newMessageAvailable = false;

char WebResponse[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n";

char WebPage[] =
"<!DOCTYPE html>" \
"<html>" \
"<head>" \
"<title>eTechPath MAX7219 ESP8266</title>" \
"<style>" \
"html, body" \ 
"{" \
"width: 600px;" \
"height: 400px;" \
"margin: 0px;" \
"border: 0px;" \
"padding: 10px;" \
"background-color: white;" \
"}" \
"#container " \
"{" \
"width: 100%;" \
"height: 100%;" \
"margin-left: 200px;" \
"border: solid 2px;" \
"padding: 10px;" \
"background-color: #b3cbf2;" \
"}" \          
"</style>"\
"<script>" \
"strLine = \"\";" \
"function SendText()" \
"{" \
"  nocache = \"/&nocache=\" + Math.random() * 1000000;" \
"  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();" \
"  strLine = \"&MSG=\" + document.getElementById(\"txt_form\").Message.value;" \
"  request.open(\"GET\", strLine + nocache, false);" \
"  request.send(null);" \
"}" \
"</script>" \
"</head>" \
"<body>" \
"<div id=\"container\">"\
"<H1><b>WiFi MAX7219 LED Matrix Display</b></H1>" \ 
"<form id=\"txt_form\" name=\"frmText\">" \
"<label>Msg:<input type=\"text\" name=\"Message\" maxlength=\"255\"></label><br><br>" \
"</form>" \
"<br>" \
"<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Send Text\" onclick=\"SendText()\">" \
"<p><b>Visit Us at</b></p>" \ 
"<a href=\"http://www.eTechPath.com\">www.eTechPath.com</a>" \
"</div>" \
"</body>" \
"</html>";

char *err2Str(wl_status_t code)
{
  switch (code)
  {
  case WL_IDLE_STATUS:    return("IDLE");           break; // WiFi is in process of changing between statuses
  case WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL:  return("NO_SSID_AVAIL");  break; // case configured SSID cannot be reached
  case WL_CONNECTED:      return("CONNECTED");      break; // successful connection is established
  case WL_CONNECT_FAILED: return("CONNECT_FAILED"); break; // password is incorrect
  case WL_DISCONNECTED:   return("CONNECT_FAILED"); break; // module is not configured in station mode
  default: return("??");
  }
}

uint8_t htoi(char c)
{
  c = toupper(c);
  if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) return(c - '0');
  if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'F')) return(c - 'A' + 0xa);
  return(0);
}

boolean getText(char *szMesg, char *psz, uint8_t len)
{
  boolean isValid = false;  // text received flag
  char *pStart, *pEnd;      // pointer to start and end of text

  // get pointer to the beginning of the text
  pStart = strstr(szMesg, "/&MSG=");

  if (pStart != NULL)
  {
    pStart += 6;  // skip to start of data
    pEnd = strstr(pStart, "/&");

    if (pEnd != NULL)
    {
      while (pStart != pEnd)
      {
        if ((*pStart == '%') && isdigit(*(pStart+1)))
        {
          // replace %xx hex code with the ASCII character
          char c = 0;
          pStart++;
          c += (htoi(*pStart++) << 4);
          c += htoi(*pStart++);
          *psz++ = c;
        }
        else
          *psz++ = *pStart++;
      }

      *psz = '\0'; // terminate the string
      isValid = true;
    }
  }

  return(isValid);
}

void handleWiFi(void)
{
  static enum { S_IDLE, S_WAIT_CONN, S_READ, S_EXTRACT, S_RESPONSE, S_DISCONN } state = S_IDLE;
  static char szBuf[1024];
  static uint16_t idxBuf = 0;
  static WiFiClient client;
  static uint32_t timeStart;

  switch (state)
  {
  case S_IDLE:   // initialise
    PRINTS("\nS_IDLE");
    idxBuf = 0;
    state = S_WAIT_CONN;
    break;

  case S_WAIT_CONN:   // waiting for connection
    {
      client = server.available();
      if (!client) break;
      if (!client.connected()) break;

#if DEBUG
      char szTxt[20];
      sprintf(szTxt, "%03d:%03d:%03d:%03d", client.remoteIP()[0], client.remoteIP()[1], client.remoteIP()[2], client.remoteIP()[3]);
      PRINT("\nNew client @ ", szTxt);
#endif

      timeStart = millis();
      state = S_READ;
    }
    break;

  case S_READ: // get the first line of data
    PRINTS("\nS_READ");
    while (client.available())
    {
      char c = client.read();
      if ((c == '\r') || (c == '\n'))
      {
        szBuf[idxBuf] = '\0';
        client.flush();
        PRINT("\nRecv: ", szBuf);
        state = S_EXTRACT;
      }
      else
        szBuf[idxBuf++] = (char)c;
    }
    if (millis() - timeStart > 1000)
    {
      PRINTS("\nWait timeout");
      state = S_DISCONN;
    }
    break;


  case S_EXTRACT: // extract data
    PRINTS("\nS_EXTRACT");
    // Extract the string from the message if there is one
    newMessageAvailable = getText(szBuf, newMessage, MESG_SIZE);
    PRINT("\nNew Msg: ", newMessage);
    state = S_RESPONSE;
    break;

  case S_RESPONSE: // send the response to the client
    PRINTS("\nS_RESPONSE");
    // Return the response to the client (web page)
    client.print(WebResponse);
    client.print(WebPage);
    state = S_DISCONN;
    break;

  case S_DISCONN: // disconnect client
    PRINTS("\nS_DISCONN");
    client.flush();
    client.stop();
    state = S_IDLE;
    break;

  default:  state = S_IDLE;
  }
}

void scrollDataSink(uint8_t dev, MD_MAX72XX::transformType_t t, uint8_t col)
// Callback function for data that is being scrolled off the display
{
#if PRINT_CALLBACK
  Serial.print("\n cb ");
  Serial.print(dev);
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.println(col);
#endif
}

uint8_t scrollDataSource(uint8_t dev, MD_MAX72XX::transformType_t t)
// Callback function for data that is required for scrolling into the display
{
  static enum { S_IDLE, S_NEXT_CHAR, S_SHOW_CHAR, S_SHOW_SPACE } state = S_IDLE;
  static char       *p;
  static uint16_t   curLen, showLen;
  static uint8_t    cBuf[8];
  uint8_t colData = 0;

  // finite state machine to control what we do on the callback
  switch (state)
  {
  case S_IDLE: // reset the message pointer and check for new message to load
    PRINTS("\nS_IDLE");
    p = curMessage;      // reset the pointer to start of message
    if (newMessageAvailable)  // there is a new message waiting
    {
      strcpy(curMessage, newMessage); // copy it in
      newMessageAvailable = false;
    }
    state = S_NEXT_CHAR;
    break;

  case S_NEXT_CHAR: // Load the next character from the font table
    PRINTS("\nS_NEXT_CHAR");
    if (*p == '\0')
      state = S_IDLE;
    else
    {
      showLen = mx.getChar(*p++, sizeof(cBuf) / sizeof(cBuf[0]), cBuf);
      curLen = 0;
      state = S_SHOW_CHAR;
    }
    break;

  case S_SHOW_CHAR: // display the next part of the character
    PRINTS("\nS_SHOW_CHAR");
    colData = cBuf[curLen++];
    if (curLen < showLen)
      break;

    // set up the inter character spacing
    showLen = (*p != '\0' ? CHAR_SPACING : (MAX_DEVICES*COL_SIZE)/2);
    curLen = 0;
    state = S_SHOW_SPACE;
    // fall through

  case S_SHOW_SPACE:    // display inter-character spacing (blank column)
    PRINT("\nS_ICSPACE: ", curLen);
    PRINT("/", showLen);
    curLen++;
    if (curLen == showLen)
      state = S_NEXT_CHAR;
    break;

  default:
    state = S_IDLE;
  }

  return(colData);
}

void scrollText(void)
{
  static uint32_t   prevTime = 0;

  // Is it time to scroll the text?
  if (millis() - prevTime >= SCROLL_DELAY)
  {
    mx.transform(MD_MAX72XX::TSL);  // scroll along - the callback will load all the data
    prevTime = millis();            // starting point for next time
  }
}

void setup()
{
#if DEBUG
  Serial.begin(115200);
  PRINTS("\n[MD_MAX72XX WiFi Message Display]\nType a message for the scrolling display from your internet browser");
#endif

#if LED_HEARTBEAT
  pinMode(HB_LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(HB_LED, LOW);
#endif

  // Display initialisation
  mx.begin();
  mx.setShiftDataInCallback(scrollDataSource);
  mx.setShiftDataOutCallback(scrollDataSink);

  curMessage[0] = newMessage[0] = '\0';

  // Connect to and initialise WiFi network
  PRINT("\nConnecting to ", ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    PRINT("\n", err2Str(WiFi.status()));
    delay(500);
  }
  PRINTS("\nWiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  PRINTS("\nServer started");

  // Set up first message as the IP address
  sprintf(curMessage, "%03d:%03d:%03d:%03d", WiFi.localIP()[0], WiFi.localIP()[1], WiFi.localIP()[2], WiFi.localIP()[3]);
  PRINT("\nAssigned IP ", curMessage);
}

void loop()
{
#if LED_HEARTBEAT
  static uint32_t timeLast = 0;

  if (millis() - timeLast >= HB_LED_TIME)
  {
    digitalWrite(HB_LED, digitalRead(HB_LED) == LOW ? HIGH : LOW);
    timeLast = millis();
  }
#endif

  handleWiFi();
  scrollText();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that you're calling the `MD_MAX72XX` constructor with the wrong arguments.

This is your current call to it:

```
MD_MAX72XX mx = MD_MAX72XX(CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);
```

The error indicates that the correct arguments are:

```
MD_MAX72XX(moduleType_t mod, uint8_t csPin, uint8_t numDevices=1);
```

The last argument has a default value. Looking at your call to the constructor, you're not passing it the `moduleType_t mod` argument. The compiler is taking `CS_PIN` to be that argument, using `MAX_DEVICES` for the `csPin` argument, and the default value of 1 for the `numDevices` argument. It throws the error you're seeing because `CS_PIN` is an integer and it's expecting a `moduleType_t`.

You can fix this by providing the correct first argument.

The [header file for the library](https://github.com/MajicDesigns/MD_MAX72XX/blob/master/src/MD_MAX72xx.h#L265) has a list of the possible values for the `mod` argument:

```
  enum moduleType_t
  {
    PAROLA_HW,    ///< Use the Parola style hardware modules.
    GENERIC_HW,   ///< Use 'generic' style hardware modules commonly available.
    ICSTATION_HW, ///< Use ICStation style hardware module.
    FC16_HW       ///< Use FC-16 style hardware module.
  };
```

Add the correct `moduleType_t` for your MAX7219 hardware as the first argument and you should see this error go away.

Comment: Thanks, but now it says `expected ')' before 'GENERIC_HW'`

Comment: What's your current line of code? It sounds like you've just got a syntax error now.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I ended using the example that came with the library

Answer (score 0):

Believe this is because of the new updates in the library, Like @John Romkey suggested the function should be called with correct number of arguments, add this line of code in your Arduino Sketch and Select the correct hardware from the list PAROLA_H, GENERIC_HW, ICSTATION_HW, FC16_HW.

```
#######define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::GENERIC_HW 
MD_Parola P = MD_Parola(HARDWARE_TYPE,CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);
```

Answer (score 0):

The library got a update and your code needs some changes to compile succesfully. Here are your options

Option-1. Modify your code to adopt updated library as suggested by John

Option-2. Use old library version. You can select library version in Arduino IDE (Sketch --> Include Library --> Manage Libraries)